# Accept button is disabled at the time of deploying an app on google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've developed a simple app which is working fine on local but when I am trying to deploy it on google app engine it shows me google prompt for sign in and after sign it shows me a page on which "accept" button is not highlighting or disabled.
screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJUnP.png
I am using eclipse luna in win vista.
If anyone have the solution please tell me.

Comment: This consent screen is part of the OAuth flow required for deployment.  The buttons are initially loaded as disabled and can sometimes take time to become clickable.  Are you still experiencing this issue?  If not, can you post your solution here to consider this question resolved?  I would also consider rewording your question to make the error/solution more clear for new readers.